# Photoshop - keyboard shortcut for "hide all other layers"

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there any way to bind "hide all other layers" to a key combination?

That you can do with the mouse by alt/option click on eye or right clicking.

I found the "hide layers" but that toggles hiding for the selected layers, I want to do the inverse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no predefined shortcut for that, but you can make an action to do it for you really easily.

- Select your active layer (the one you want to show)
- Window => Actions
- Click on 'New Action', select the shortcut you want (I chose <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).
- You now see a recoding dot (red). <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on the eye of your layer.
- Click on the 'Stop' icon to stop recording your action (just beside the red dot in the actions window).

Now you should be able to select any layer and press your shortcut (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for me) to hide all other layers.

*Actions panel in PS CS6*

[image: Actions panel in PS CS6]

Comment: Don't work for me (CS5 windows). The action created is bound to the specific layer I clicked when recording, not the selected layer.
And it is bound to ether show or hide, not both.

Comment: So right click and show/hide don't work, BUT alt click do! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for a shortcut for that action too, hope it's not too late but there's another way to do it (works for me in CC).

• press alt and left Click on the eye icon of the layer you want to keep visible.

Until now this is the fastest way that i know.